# Graphics not working after kernel upgrade

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, intel

My Ubuntu 22.04 kernel was recently upgraded to 5.19.0-42, at which point the graphics rendering switched from hardware (intel whiskey lake) to software (llvmpipe). This has happened once before, and back then I managed to solve the problem by following the procedure decribed here: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-jammy-arc.html
However, as the headers for 5.19.0-35 does not exist anymore I cant use that kernel, and I have not currently made it work on 5.19.0-42.
Does anyone have an idea on what I can do? Right now Im stuck with tty which is really frustrating.

Comment: Usually, the intel drivers will come with a kernel update. (If you use the standard drivers, which I assume). You might try to switch to Xserver session (log out and select it on the cog on the right side) and check again